# Preserving Adminhtml Grid Filter Parameters After a Redirect

Tags: admin, adminhtml, grid, controllers, redirect

As title says, I'd like to keep the filtering parameters for a custom grid I made in the admin.

For example, if I filter the grid, edit a row, and save, I'd like to be redirected to the grid and have the same filters applied. I've tried `_redirectReferer()` and poked around some admin controllers, but I didn't find anything in particular.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Im not entirely sure, but using             `$this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);`
in

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('module_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('rule_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
```

might do the trick.

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I tried clearing session to relogin to repeat the steps, but it's the same.

Comment: Are you sure you set the correct ID?
`$this->setId('grid_id');`